# StrictMode DiskReadViolation on ListView fling

Tags: android

My fragment is generating a huge bunch of disk read Strict mode violations and flashing the screen when i do a small fling or a scroll. I am running the app on a Samsung with Android 4.4.2.

The list view in the fragment is populated from a custom content provider using a custom cursor adaptor. I have not handled any fling or scroll events that might trigger a disk read. Getting these violations when the fragment starts is reasonable  because i do `getLoaderManager().initLoader()` in `onResume()`. But I don't understand why the fragment would attempt a disk read on a fling.

Out of the approx 500 logcat lines with Tag `StrictMode` generated, I have pasted just a few here.  Any idea what is causing this?

```
@TargetApi(11)
public static void enableStrictMode() {
        // Strict mode is only available on gingerbread or later
        if (Utils.hasGingerbread()) {

            // Enable all thread strict mode policies
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder threadPolicyBuilder =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                            .detectAll()
                            .penaltyLog();

            // Enable all VM strict mode policies
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder vmPolicyBuilder =
                    new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                            .detectAll()
                            .penaltyLog();

            // Honeycomb introduced some additional strict mode features
            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                // Flash screen when thread policy is violated
                threadPolicyBuilder.penaltyFlashScreen();
                // For each activity class, set an instance limit of 1. Any more instances and
                // there could be a memory leak.
                vmPolicyBuilder
                        .setClassInstanceLimit(ContactsListActivity.class, 1)
                        .setClassInstanceLimit(ContactDetailActivity.class, 1);
            }

            // Use builders to enable strict mode policies
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicyBuilder.build());
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(vmPolicyBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

**Logcat :**

```
    StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=15 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=2335 violation=2
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1156)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:106)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.SSRMUtil.writeSysfs(SSRMUtil.java:134)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.acquireCpuDvfsLock(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:2321)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.acquireDVFSLockLocked(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:1929)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.acquireDVFSLock(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:1880)
    at android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager$Stub.onTransact(ICustomFrequencyManager.java:274)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
# via Binder call with stack:
android.os.StrictMode$LogStackTrace
    at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:1726)
    at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:1447)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1416)
    at android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireDVFSLock(ICustomFrequencyManager.java:766)
    at android.os.CustomFrequencyManager$CPUDVFSControlRequest.doFrequencyRequestImpl(CustomFrequencyManager.java:458)
    at android.os.CustomFrequencyManager$FrequencyRequest.doFrequencyRequest(CustomFrequencyManager.java:218)
    at android.os.DVFSHelper.acquire(DVFSHelper.java:495)
    at android.os.DVFSHelper.acquire(DVFSHelper.java:288)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.reportScrollStateChange(AbsListView.java:5433)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3858)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4745)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4600)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8149)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2140)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2565)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2243)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8357)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4778)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
    at 
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=14 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=2335 violation=1
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1130)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:196)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:450)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.SSRMUtil.writeSysfs(SSRMUtil.java:135)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.acquireCpuDvfsLock(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:2321)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.acquireDVFSLockLocked(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:1929)
    at com.android.server.ssrm.CustomFrequencyManagerService.acquireDVFSLock(CustomFrequencyManagerService.java:1880)
    at android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager$Stub.onTransact(ICustomFrequencyManager.java:274)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
# via Binder call with stack:
android.os.StrictMode$LogStackTrace
    at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:1726)
    at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:1447)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1416)
    at android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireDVFSLock(ICustomFrequencyManager.java:766)
    at android.os.CustomFrequencyManager$CPUDVFSControlRequest.doFrequencyRequestImpl(CustomFrequencyManager.java:458)
    at android.os.CustomFrequencyManager$FrequencyRequest.doFrequencyRequest(CustomFrequencyManager.java:218)
    at android.os.DVFSHelper.acquire(DVFSHelper.java:495)
    at android.os.DVFSHelper.acquire(DVFSHelper.java:288)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.reportScrollStateChange(AbsListView.java:5433)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3858)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4745)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4600)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8149)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2140)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2155)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2565)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2243)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8357)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4778)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
```

Comment: Samsungs-specific code is doing something fishy there. "com.android.server.ssrm.*" is Samsung-specific. More about DVFS: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.dvfs

Comment: @HansKratz you might be onto something. I think the issue started only after the 4.4.2 update. I do get the GC warning (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637835/pause-gc-error-post-android-4-4-2-upgrade ) as well before the strict mode violations