# Android Service: InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

I have the following error but cannot determine a solution that works:

```
02-17 22:58:21.636  27014-27014/com.example.feastapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Pause GC
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The action that leads to the error is the send message action, specifically on the line `imService.sendGroupMessage`:

```
    // Send message
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        CharSequence message;
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (selectedLocationId == null) {
                selectedLocationId = "0";
            }


            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        if (imService.sendGroupMessage(group.groupId,
                                group.groupName, enteredMessage.getText().toString(), sharedSpecialId, selectedLocationId) == null) {

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {

                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "It's null...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();

        }
    });
```

I do have the activity bind to the service on creation with:

```
private Manager imService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        imService = null;
        Toast.makeText(SharingAction.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Why would this error occur, when I have other class setup just like this with no error?

Comment: Does your MessagingService attempt to start an activity for any reason? The stack trace, while not indicating any direct fault in your code, is failing during an attempt to launch a new activity from an intent.

Comment: No, it should not try to start a new activity. What line in the trace indicates this?

Comment: The lines for `performLaunchActivity()` and `handleLaunchActivity()`. That means the crash happened while attempting to start an activity from an intent..whether it came from your service or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this happening on a real device? Have you tested on other devices or simulator? Maybe you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637835/pause-gc-error-post-android-4-4-2-upgrade) question or [this](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=266242) forum

Comment: Yes, it's a real device. I will probably just use Volley as this functionality does not need to be real time.