# High memory allocation causes outofmemory crash

Tags: android, memory-management, xamarin, json.net

We are developing an that app is crashing quite a lot with the following exeption:

```
Java.Lang.Error null
--- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Using the Xamarin profiler I see that the app keaps allocating memory and the memory is not freed up anymore. 
[image]

Expanding the call tree shows that loading a small json file allocateds 6,1mb??
This file is a small login file containing just the login data of the user:
[image]

Is this memory that is currently used by newtonsoft? At the point where the snapshot is taken this activity should not be active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is due to the device we are using. On the Note 2 on android 4.4 Samsung introduced an issue with the GC causes the GC not to run.

[Pause GC Error post android 4.4.2 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637835/pause-gc-error-post-android-4-4-2-upgrade)

We will be downgrading our devices. We did a quick test on 4.3 wich does not crash after 3 test runs.